# Can I intercept the loading of an iframe and modify the contentWindow?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to provide a property to an iframe via its contentWindow and would like to do it in a synchronous manner.

I know I can access and set properties on the `contentWindow` of the iframe but the modification will occur after the iframe has loaded.

Parent

```html
<body>
  <script>
    const frame = document.createElement('iframe')
    document.body.appendChild(frame)
    frame.src = 'frame.html'
    frame.contentWindow.foobar = 'foobar'
  </script>
</body>
```

iframe

```html
<body>
  <script>
    console.log(window.foobar) // undefined
  </script>
</body>
```

Is it possible to achieve or do I have to do this asynchronously by dispatching an event from the parent notifying the iframe that the property has been set?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I have to think there's a way to do this, since replit.com seems to be able to override the `window.console` inside the preview frame.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this. My goal was to create a "mock console" where any calls to `console.log` in the iframe document would be intercepted by the parent window. The problem was similar to OP's in that even though I overrode `frame.contentWindow.console`, it seemed to get re-set when the window loaded.

I'm not sure how exactly I solved it (I tried copying the replit previewer, luckily they had sourcemaps enabled), but nonetheless here is a plunkr showing a working example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/OLQ0wm8sZVUlMT0p?open=lib%2Fscript.js

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Preview frame</p>
    <div id="userCodePreviewWrapper"></div>
    <p>Mock Console</p>
    <div id="mockConsole"></div>
    <script>

      let contentWindow;
      const consoleDiv = document.querySelector('#mockConsole');

      function createConsole(frame) {
        // Override the console object in the frame
        contentWindow = frame.contentWindow;
        frame.contentWindow.__nativeConsole = frame.contentWindow.console;
        frame.contentWindow.console = {
          log: function(msg) {
            console.log("Logging console message", msg);
            consoleDiv.innerHTML += `<p>${msg}</p>`;
          }
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const previewFrameDiv = document.querySelector('#userCodePreviewWrapper');

        const previewFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
        previewFrame.src = 'user-code.html';
        previewFrame.setAttribute('id', 'userCodePreview');
        previewFrame.setAttribute(
          'sandbox',
          'allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups ' +
            'allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals',
        );
        previewFrame.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);

        previewFrameDiv.appendChild(previewFrame);

        createConsole(previewFrame);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```